# Is there a way to hide the tag of las commit merged?

Tags: git, merge, tags

The branch that I have checked out is:

```
release/3.4.0
```

so that's what I should see in the direction bar of my terminal, but I get this instead:

```
release/3.4.0 ng-client-project-3.4.0-1022-47ce1a32a4b0f7063474439df18fd01050c064b8
```

The second part is the tag of the commit from the last branch merged into `release/3.4.0`

If I do `git branch` it shows me I am in `release/3.4.0` but I keep getting the tag in the terminal direction bar.

I have tried deleting the branch and `git pull`, but no changes, no other partner has something like that in this project.

I can't find info about what this means or implications.

I don't know why I see the tag, and I don't want to see it. I don't want to delete anything.

The direction bar of the terminal is my prompt.

I have a Mac with Big Sur 11.5.2 my shell is zsh, and have installed ohMyzsh

Comment: I'm not sure understand correctly. You don't want to delete the tag, you want to hide the tag name displayed in your terminal, am I right?

Comment: What's the "direction bar of the terminal" ? The title of the graphical window that contains your terminal ? or your prompt ? (the text that appears as a prefix each time you are prompted for a command)

Comment: Also : what are your OS and shell ?